# How to display CFC Data via AJAX

Tags: ajax, coldfusion, cfc

I'm having a tough time figuring this out and I'm a real novice at AJAX. I'm making a call to a CFC via an AJAX request. I'm getting JSON data returned as I can see the results in firebug, I'm just unable to display the query results it into my div.

Can someone show me how to do this?

**My Javascript**

```
<script>
        // populate the dropdown

          // on change of dropdown value return the cfc data into the div
        $("##company_name").change(function() {  
            var selectValue = $("##company_name").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url:"cfcs/alertData.cfc?method=getAlerts",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { 
                    returnFormat: 'json',
                    company_name: selectValue
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $("##test").html(data);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    $("##test").html('Failed');
                }
            });
        });
          </script>
```

**My Div**

```
<div id="test">test</div>
```

**My CFC**

```
<cffunction name="getAlerts" access="remote" returntype="query">
    <cfargument name="company_name" type="any" required="true">

    <!--- localize function variables --->
    <cfset var alertDetail = "">

    <cfquery name="getID" datasource="#datasource#" >
        select customer_id
        from customer_table
        where company_name = <cfqueryparam value="#ARGUMENTS.company_name#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
    </cfquery> 
    <cfquery name="alertDetail" datasource="#datasource#">
        SELECT ID
        FROM   customer_alerts
        <!--- adjust cfsqltype if needed --->
        WHERE customer_id = <cfqueryparam value="#getID.customer_id#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"> AND alert_status = 'on'
    </cfquery>    

    <cfreturn alertDetail>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: Is your script tag nested inside a cfoutput?  If not, which there would be no reason too... remove the ## for #.  Also, .success, .error is the old way of doing it... .done, .fail, .always is how its done now:  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ examples at the bottom

Comment: Yes, it's in a cfoutput tag. Is there anything that with my current code that would prevent the div from showing the data I'm retrieving?

Comment: What gets put in the `<div>` currently? Does it just keep the "test" placeholder value?

Comment: Well the div is currently empty, so when I fire the AJAX request, it stays empty. But when I add the word 'test' to my div and re-run everything, the word 'test' is removed and the div becomes blank. And it is not adding the word 'Failed' which is what the error part of my AJAX is supposed to do, so I can only assume that the success part of the AJAX call is actually running. No errors in firebug console.

Comment: Maybe you need to convert the `data` variable to a STRING using `toString() ` before you output it inside the `.html();` part? Otherwise, isn't `data` a JavaScript object (which can't be rendered into HTML) ?

Comment: @CarlVonStetten He would at least get [object Object] if that were the case

Comment: I don't see anything with your current code that would make it print an empty string rather than `[object Object]`, try `console.log(data)` and reading the console.

Comment: Console.log shows: Object {COLUMNS: Array[3], DATA: Array[1]}

Comment: Anyone have any suggestions??. I'm at a total loss. Thanks.

Comment: Try console.log( data.DATA[0] );
It looks like the cfquery is being returned, but not in the flat structure you're expecting.  My guess is that you will see what you expected in data.DATA[0]

Comment: It shows: [1, "This is a test", "high"] . Those are the 3 collums that my query is returning. So the data is there, thats a good sign. How do I format it so that I cn show it in my div?